# Mysqli using mysql variable error

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I´ve finally created my account here. You´ve been helping me for a long time, but this time I couldn´t find a answer here.

I new in MySqli and I´m trying to run a script that worked in phpMyAdmin.

The trouble happens when I try to use a 'mysql variable'. The code and error are below.

```
$consulta = "SET @var= (SELECT ticket_id FROM ost_ticket WHERE number = 410037);

SELECT DISTINCT a.number, a.created, b.address, 
SELECT DISTINCT title FROM ost_ticket_thread a WHERE a.ticket_id = @var AND a.source LIKE  'API')title, 
SELECT DISTINCT body FROM ost_ticket_thread a WHERE a.ticket_id = @var AND a.source LIKE  'API')body,
d.state, 
c.body resposta
FROM ost_ticket a
LEFT JOIN ost_user_email b ON b.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN ost_ticket_thread c ON c.ticket_id = a.ticket_id
LEFT JOIN ost_ticket_status d ON d.id = a.status_id
WHERE a.ticket_id = @var AND c.id = (SELECT MAX( a.id ) FROM ost_ticket_thread a WHERE a.ticket_id = @var ) ";


$resultado = $MySQLi->query($consulta) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);

$cont = 0;

while ($informacao = $resultado->fetch_object()) {


$data[$cont] = array(
'numprot'      =>      $informacao->number,
'email'     =>      $informacao->address,
'assunto'     =>      $informacao->title,
'status'     =>      $informacao->state,
'body'     =>      $informacao->body,
'resposta'     =>      $informacao->resposta,
'dtcriacao'     =>      $informacao->created,
);

$cont++;

}

echo "{'lista':".json_encode($data)."}";
```

As I said, it worked fine in phpMyAdmin but I got the followed Error in mysqli query function.

```
Fatal error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT distinct a.number,a.created,b.address, (select distinct title from ost_t' at line 3 in /home/u605553750/public_html/JSONResposta.php on line 22
```

The line 22 matches at

```
 $resultado = $MySQLi->query($consulta) OR trigger_error($MySQLi->error, E_USER_ERROR);
```

What´s the right way to run it on MySqli?

Thanks
Bruno

Comment: When you copy and paste this SQL query on your PHP admin does it execute? It seems you have spelling errors, but I dont know if `MariaDB` allows : `b.address, (another select) x`... Also, it is considered good practice to keep SQL commands in uppercase, makes maintenance easier

Comment: It does worked. I coded it on phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I think the problem is the fact that be using "SET @var=..." with a ";" in the end.

Comment: My main guess is the `;` operator. I do not use mariadb, so I dont know its limitations/quirks...

Comment: Please, [check this links for multiple statement operations](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot the from on that line.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.number,a.created,b.address [FROM YOURTABLE]<-add this, (...
```

After clarification I think I understand your intent better, in that case, you should make sure that your subquery's return a select_expression. Notice the "AS"?

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.number,a.created,b.address, 
(SELECT DISTINCT title FROM ost_ticket_thread a WHERE a.ticket_id = @var AND a.source LIKE  'API') AS title
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Please, instead of w3schools, use the official documentation (such as [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php), or an manual from that specific Database...thumbs up on the answer anyway.... [and to justify why w3schools is bad, read this link](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: I feel like the official documentation is a bit harsh for this question, but you are absolutely correct, the w3c schools leave a very skewed view of things :)

Comment: My main issue with that site is the outdated information, and the over simplistic definitions it uses... finally, sometimes the suggested implementation that offers major security holes, that older developers tend to have to fix later (such as never cleaning input, or droping database details in the html page, etc..)

Comment: This part is ok, I just got a field from an other SELECT but the mais select is few lines below "FROM ost_ticket a".

Comment: I tried the way u said using "AS", but i got the same error. The sql code is working, the problem is make it work with "MySqli_query" function. I think the problem is the fact that be using "SET @var=..." with a ";" in the end.